# Unable to install threading with Anaconda 64-bit

Tags: parallel-processing, python-3.4

When I pip install or conda install "threading" I get an error saying it cannot be found, I am having a similar problem with Queue. Does Anaconda only fetch 64-bit libraries? I am trying to go through Parallel Programming with Python.

How do I install this library correctly?

Is any other information is needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried "import threading" and "import Queue" in your code? They are both standard libs in Python. There should be no need for an install.